How to replace this spigot washer?
This is the stem from an outdoor spigot.  The washer has failed. The "screw", if it is a screw, holding the washer is perfectly smooth and round. No provision for any screwdriver.
Have you seen one like this, and how do you change the washer?



If the new washer is flexible enough, perhaps it just pops over. The old one likely has to be broken off, as rubber tends to harden with age.

It almost looks like a locking pliers job, but then you think who makes something that needs locking pliers to remove/put on.

@crip659 the chip on the right was made by my locking pliers.  One mis-step ahead of you. ;)

@Ecnerwal bingo.  Realizing that breaking off the old washer has no disadvantage, I did so and it's clear you're correct.  I'll post pics in an answer.

Thanks to @Ecnerwal for solving this in a comment.
The "screw" is not a screw, it's all one piece, and the new washer easily stretches over the domed cap.  No tools, it was so easy, I wonder why these were ever made with screws and why I've never seen this before.



Happy to help, glad I guessed right. I don't need points, so I'll not be bothering with posting an actual answer. The screws likely date back to when they were leather, and then the building industry's vast inability to accept new technology even when they accepted rubber over leather for the washers...and of course some of them are very hard rubber, which is probably trying to make them more like leather...

Buy another one. Take off the top and screw it into the body of the one that is already installed. They make repair kits for these things, but you might just find it easier to just replace the whole valve body.

If I have to buy a new one, I'll buy a better one and replace the whole thing.
